# SSL Certificate with PHP CURL

Tags: php, xml, ssl, curl

I'm using curl to send an xml file over https to the rightmove API - they supplied me with all the certificates.

I am getting the error :

> 60SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
>   certificateResult =

I have tried everything i have found on every other stackoverflow post similar and nothing is working, i have tried downloading the old cacert.pem and changed the files in php.ini - ive installed my personal information file andcreated a certificate on the browser and local machine and nothing is removing the error 60.

This is my PHP :

```
<?php
  $xml = file_get_contents("myxml.xml");

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__).'\mypem.pem');

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://adfapi.adftest.rightmove.com/v1/property/sendpropertydetails");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://adfapi.adftest.rightmove.com/v1/property/sendpropertydetails');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE , 1);

  $ch_result = curl_exec($ch);
print curl_errno($ch);
print curl_error($ch);
  echo "Result = ".$ch_result;
  curl_close($ch);

?>
```

this has had me banging my head for days, i would be very grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Try setting curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); and remove curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

Comment: @Indrajit Thanks indrajit, but the api requires authentication

Comment: Presumably you're not getting the same error in your browser. Either you're not up to date with your patching or you've installed a version of PHP which is not correctly configured for your platform.

Comment: Im getting this error locally, on my web server and on my server at work.@symcbean, but yes you are correct, i can navigate therein browser no problem.

Comment: Still not been able to solve this after a full day trying

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For my particular case i needed to add the keyfile, sslcert and cert password.

```
   //$xml = file_get_contents("thexmlfile.xml");
  $xml= $propertyXml->asXML();
  $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . '\pemfile.pem');

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://adfapi.adftest.rightmove.com/v1/property/sendpropertydetails");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE, getcwd() . '\myjks.jks');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd() . '\pemfile.pem');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, "thesslpassword");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://adfapi.adftest.rightmove.com/v1/property/sendpropertydetails");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE , 1);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  $ch_result = curl_exec($ch);
print curl_errno($ch);
print curl_error($ch);
  echo "Result = ".$ch_result;
  curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Can you please paste the whole curl request please. I am struggling too with Curl Request for Rightmove for couple of days.

Comment: Thanks, This helped me till date

Answer (score 3):

It is failing as curl is unable to verify the certificate provided by the server.

There are two options to get this to work:

1 Allows curl to make insecure connections, that is curl does not verify the certificate.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

2 Add the root CA (the CA signing the server certificate) in php.ini

```
curl.cainfo=/path/to/cacert.pem
```

You should use option 2 as thats the option that ensures that you are connecting to secure ftp server.

Comment: I tired option 2 with cacert.pem (multiple ones i found on the internet from other posts) and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: And ofcourse the api returns auth failed if i try to not verify the host

Comment: when i change the curl.cainfo i get this : 60SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificateResult =

Comment: @GazSmith [using curl ssl](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/) check this link

Comment: Thanks @walkingRed, although i still having an authentication issue from rightmoves api so the certificates must be wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificateResult" error with HTTP GET to a remote https site.  I only needed to provide the CA cert to php curl, ie CURLOPT_CAINFO:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/path/to/CA_Bundle.crt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
  $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
  print "curl_error: $error_msg <br>";
} else {
  print "output: $output<br>";
}

curl_close($ch);
```