# cURL works from command line, but not from PHP

Tags: php, curl, command-line

My targeted site is behind cloudflare.

I am getting `200` Response code, for `cURL` command line:

```
curl -d "data=data1" -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0' -X POST https://data.mysite.com
```

And getting `403` Response code, for `cURL` PHP:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://data.mysite.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "data=data1");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

I have checked the curl request for both. Both are sending same header, using same root certificate. Only difference is SSL connecting cipher.

Command line is using:
`TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`

And php is using:
`TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`

Is the cipher playing the major role here??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSL Certificate with PHP CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131857/ssl-certificate-with-php-curl)

Comment: @nice_dev thanks, i saw it before. but `cURL` is not throwing any error. So i dont think it will help me. 
Is it possible to force cURL to use specific cipher?

Comment: Try removing ```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);```

Comment: @Vagabond same issue. Even, it behaves same as php if i remove `useragent` from command line too